# modifying the ajax path of drupal ajax module forms submission

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm using the [Ajax module](http://drupal.org/project/ajax) and following [this documentation](http://drupal.org/node/349961).

The thing is, my form is loaded via ahah, and when that happens whenever I submit the form, this modules make an ajax call to a messed up path (if it weren't loaded via ahah, the ajax that the form loads is fine)

Do any of you know how I can modify the path of this module's ajax call so that I can fix it accordingly?